# Multiple steps user registration - relation between php session and javascript variables

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, user-registration

I am doing in PHP/MySQL a user registration in multiple steps. Everything is on the same page. I have declared functions for each of the step and hold a variable of the current step (or next if certain conditions apply) in `$_SESSION`. I also keep the values for each step into `$_SESSION` and at the last step I will write everything to the database.

On my last step I need to work on the client side to allow user to choose a few cities in his/her state where they activate. I do this with jQuery autocomplete and the autocomplete source data is taken using AJAX/PHP from the database (no refresh required). I have a textbox for the user to add cities and a div where I insert the cities selected (allowing the option to delete them in case of mistake insertion). All this is happening on the client side.

I need to somehow get the client side array of the cities selected (which includes city_id, city_name and county_name) and put it into the `$_SESSION` so that when I need to write into the database I have everything in order.

How do I do it?

Only option that I have in mind right now is to pass the JS array with ajax to a php file which will insert into session the JS array. I am thinking to do that before the page submission and to allow for the form to be submitted, get to the next step which is the step where I write everything to the database.

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is your best option

I would do it "on change" and fire it off to a php script to store it in session.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not send random bits of information to the server everytime I ask for something from the user; it could lead to having many small scripts handling 1 thing each, or 1 giant and ever growing controller (bad smells)

I would just save everything within javascript (into an Object, or if you want persistence on page refreshes, use localstorage), then send all the information in one go at the last step.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? "send random bits of information to the server ....". Basically what I need to do is collect all the cities the user is active in and then, only then, I want to send data to php $_SESSION.